# Cannot display Playground Result.json using MongoDB for vscode

Tags: json, mongodb, visual-studio-code

When i launch queries from a playground(.mongodb) file using the mongodb extension for vscode the result is correctly printed in the console of vscode but it doesn’t appear the json tab(Playground result.json) showing the same result but in json format…(as it should happen according to the documentation)
I’m using vscode for macbook

Answer (score 0):

Was your query without print command? (e.g. *db.tests* instead of *print(db.tests)*)

If so

> Note that print and console.log will print in the VS Code Output
> panel, while the result of the playground is displayed in an editor.

See https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/print-function-in-vscode-extension-is-missing/103118/2